# Hide or unhide text with button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to html and this is our first intro homework assignment for javascript; so naturally I am freaking out! Here is an example of what I'm talking about:

```
<div class="someclassname"> <a href="image.jpg">
           <img src= Image/image.jpg height="80">
    </a>
    <p>some text to he hidden with the image!</p>
</div>
```

I have looked everywhere and found similar stuff but I am way to incompetent to translate it into what I am doing

I'm thinking the code should look something like this maybe?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("Button").click(function() {
$(".someclassname").toggle();
if ($.trim($(this).text()) == 'Hide') {
$(this).text('Show');
} else {
$(this).next('Hide');
}
});
</script>
```

Am I close? Please help!

Comment: You're more likely to get useful help if you tell us what the code you posted does.  As is, "Am I close?" suggests you haven't even tried it yet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close enough...

You have a syntax error in your script, missing pair of `})` and then place a button in your html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $(".someclassname").toggle();
    if ($.trim($(this).text()) == 'Hide') {
      $(this).text('Show');
    } else {
      $(this).next('Hide');
    }
  });
}); //this is missing
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Hide</button>
<div class="someclassname">
  <a href="image.jpg">
    <img src="Image/image.jpg" height="80" />
  </a>
  <p>some text to he hidden with the image!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes I was so close! I had also forgot to put in "$(".someclassname").hide(); to hide the initial text. Thanks for the help. Also very fast response!